# Golang doesn't recognize Close-Notifier

Tags: apache, go, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

when I use Apache mod_proxy to forward my go-requests to my golang-webserver, my go-server doesn't recognize when client disconnects. I am using the close notifier:

```
notify := rw.(http.CloseNotifier).CloseNotify()
go func() {
        <-notify
        brk.closingClients <- cl.session.Value
}
```

When I use firewall sitepath rooting it doesn't work either.
But when I use my own golang reverse proxy it works verry well without any problems.
With my apache mod_proxy the client receives the notify after some more real data sended to the go webserver.

Perhaps somebody have a idea how can i solve my problem, that i recognize when clients disconnect directly, so without receiving any more data.

Here my mod_proxy configs

```
     SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyRequests On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    ProxyPass /event https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8888/event flushpackets=on  keepalive=on
```

Comment: Just a quick thought, but isn't **not closing the connection** exactly what the `keepalive=on` flag in your proxy configuration is supposed to be doing?

Comment: that flag prevents the firewall from dropping the connection when the connection is inactive. So i tried your idea and removed the flag, but i have the same problem.

Comment: maybe apache uses a pool of connections to your go server?

Comment: How do i know, if apache uses a pool?

Comment: @user2715821, Error log level "debug" dumps these gory details (such as initializing workers, selecting them etc) into the log sink associated with your virtual host / whatever.

Answer (score 3):

The Apache server isn't going to close the connection when the client disconnects. It's much more efficient for it to reuse the connection for as long as possible.

If you *really* want the reverse proxy to reconnect every time (beware you may run into performance or port allocation issues), you can force `mod_proxy` to use HTTP/1.0 or explicitly close the connections every time with either of:

```
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#envsettings